# JS encapsulation issue: "this.foo = new function(){...};" vs "this.Bar = function(){..}; this.foo = new Bar();"

Tags: javascript, function, oop, encapsulation

Not entirely sure why one works and the other does not. Could someone please explain this? I'm new to JavaScript. I've been reading [this guide](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/) so far.

**This works. Data is considered to be a local variable of the _fSettings object.**

```
ENTRANCE_APP._fSettings = function(){
    var data = new StorageObject('settings');
    /** The selected camera index. **/
    var cameraIndex = data.getValue('cameraIndex','0');
    this.setCameraIndex = function(index)   {cameraIndex = index;};
    this.getCameraIndex = function()    {return cameraIndex;};
};
ENTRANCE_APP.settings = new ENTRANCE_APP._fSettings();
```

**But this does not? data is considered to be a global variable after that first declaration.  So 'data.getValue(...)' treats data as a global variable.**

```
ENTRANCE_APP.settings = new function(){
    var data = new StorageObject('settings');
    /** The selected camera index. **/
    var cameraIndex = data.getValue('cameraIndex','0');
    this.setCameraIndex = function(index)   {cameraIndex = index;};
    this.getCameraIndex = function()    {return cameraIndex;};
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try treating it as an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) like this:

```
ENTRANCE_APP.settings = new (function(){
    var data = new StorageObject('settings');
    /** The selected camera index. **/
    var cameraIndex = data.getValue('cameraIndex','0');
    this.setCameraIndex = function(index)   {cameraIndex = index;};
    this.getCameraIndex = function()    {return cameraIndex;};
})();
```

Notice the parentheses surrounding the function to create a function expression and the parentheses after it to invoke the function.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oJp9o.jpg
Alright. Tried your solution, and data is still being highlighted in the IDE as an undeclared global variable. Perhaps this is an issue with my IDE?

Comment: Note that jslint doesn't like this at all, if you're into that sort of thing. The construction `var foo = new (function () {})();` will report "Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function.". But the construction `var foo = new (function () {}());` is a syntax error in this case. For the sake of having useful stack traces, I highly encourage you to give the function a name like `function EntranceAppSettings() {}`, and invoke it like `ENTRANCE_APP.settings = new EntranceAppSettings()`.

Comment: @TaylorLove I'm not sure what IDE you're using, but it really doesn't make sense that it warns you about an undeclared variable *on the declaration of that variable*.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I'd agree with that. OP's original solution seems a cleaner.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Eureka! Joe, you were right. Naming the function seems to solve the issue I've been having. It would seem that the NETBEANS IDE I am using does not like unnamed functions being used this way. So giving it a name fixes the warning. Thanks a million, sir! http://i.stack.imgur.com/wR2NC.jpg

Comment: On the point of the IDE highlighting: Generally, if the variable declaration is highlighted, it is warning you of *unused variables*, which seems to be the case here.